# Sum and group consecutive integers

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, gaps-and-islands

I need to sum and group consecutive integers by `spoken_correctly` > 0.

I'm able to find out which sections are consecutive by looking at `lag` and `lead`, but then am not sure how to sum contiguous groups `consecutive` field's values.

I.e., I have two groups where there are consecutive `spoken_correctly` values > 0. The first group in green has three rows of non-zero `spoken_correctly`, the second group in green has two.

[image]

**Desired output:**

[image]

This SQL produces the first image above output:

```
select *, case when (q.times_spoken_correctly > 0 and (q.lag > 0 or q.lead > 0)) then 1 else 0 end as consecutive
from (
    select *, lag(q.times_spoken_correctly) over (partition by q.profile_id order by q.profile_id) as lag, lead(q.times_spoken_correctly) over (partition by q.profile_id order by q.profile_id) as lead
    from (
        SELECT *
        FROM ( VALUES (3, 0, '2019-01-15 19:15:06'),
                      (3, 0, '2019-01-15 19:15:07'),
                      (3, 1, '2019-01-15 19:16:06'),
                      (3, 2, '2019-01-15 19:16:10'),
                      (3, 2, '2019-01-15 19:17:06'),
                      (3, 0, '2019-01-15 19:17:11'),
                      (3, 0, '2019-01-15 19:39:06'),
                      (3, 3, '2019-01-15 19:40:10'),
                      (3, 4, '2019-01-15 19:40:45')
             ) AS baz ("profile_id", "times_spoken_correctly", "w_created_at")
    ) as q
) as q
```

Comment: How do you know which one is consecutive? Is there any other id / date column specifying the order?

Comment: @KaushikNayak sorry updated above

Comment: Can you add the data in plain text format? It is hard to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @KaushikNayak the query provided sets up the table / values for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a gaps and islands problem, which can be solved by forming groups of sequences using `row_number`

```
select profile_id, count(*)  as consec FROM 
(
SELECT t.*, row_number() OVER ( PARTITION BY profile_id  ORDER BY w_created_at ) -
            row_number() OVER ( PARTITION BY profile_id, CASE times_spoken_correctly 
                         WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END 
            ORDER BY w_created_at ) as seq --group zeros and non zeros
            FROM t ORDER BY w_created_at
    ) s WHERE  times_spoken_correctly > 0 --to count only "> zero" groups.
    GROUP BY profile_id,seq;
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=43a3b5dbd3d9073241c2c8dc76ec650c)

Comment: thanks so much! but this doesn't work for multiple profile IDs. I recognize the original question did not have other profile IDs other than 3, but I have to perform this grouping for each profile ID

Comment: @Growler : It works : Check this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=d5faa008fc49529b02d47376cb06bbea

Comment: Ah yes I see. Can you explain how `row_number()` helps here? I'm a bit lost

Comment: @Growler : I've used standard gaps and islands approach: I could explain it, but there are several good articles explaining the technique already which you can find over the internet. For eg: [this](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/)